# What is the best method to loop through an object and then update its properties according to this task below?

Tags: object, if-statement, properties, key-value

I am trying to solve this problem:

*"Use given object and loop through its properties - if it has property “discount”, print “Already discounted by…” and add the value (how much the discount was). In the opposite case, check the price, depending on it (if it is greater or lower than 100), add a discount (10% if greater, 7% if lower) and add the property “discount” to the object."*

I came up with this to find the discounted price (if you uncomment the discount it should lead to the first result) but I find this extremely ugly... Am I following the wrong path?
Any advice will be highly appreciated!

```
let prod = {
  name: 'headphones',
  price: 83.7,
  //discount: "7%",
}
  
if (prod.discount) {
  console.log(`Already discounted by ${prod.discount}`)
}

else if (prod.price >= 100) {
  discount = ((prod.price / 100) * 10);
  prod.price = (prod.price - discount); 
}

else {
  discount = ((prod.price / 100) * 7);
  prod.price = (prod.price - discount); 
};

console.log(prod.price);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing how this is a matter of opinion, if it were up to me, you would define the discount property at the beginning as an empty string `""`. Then you would check the length of the property to see if it has been applied, or ideally use a separate property to track if the discount was applied.
Otherwise, the semantic `if (prod.discount)` is commonly used in professional JS settings so i don't see a problem with it.
I would recommend doing this:

```js
let prod = {
  name: 'headphones',
  price: 83.7,
  discount: "",
}
  
if (prod.discount.length) {
  console.log(`Already discounted by ${prod.discount}`)
}
```

This way you don't rely on uninitialized properties.